# How do I cook bolognese-filled ravioli from frozen?

Tags: freezing, pasta, ravioli

I'm planning on following [Jamie Olvier's bolognese ravioli recipe](https://www.lifestylefood.com.au/recipes/24842/bolognese-ravioli), freezing the ravioli and then cooking and serving them the next day.

When talking about cooking them, the recipe says:

> Cook the ravioli in the boiling salted water for 3 minutes, or until
>   tender, then use a slotted spoon to transfer them to the sauce. Gently
>   toss together and simmer for another couple of minutes [...]

But earlier in the recipe, where it talks about freezing them:

> [...] or make a double batch of pasta and freeze as ravioli – you can cook
>   them from frozen in the sauce.

Does that mean I don't cook the frozen ravioli in boiling water at all? And, as the recipe doesn't say, how long would you recommend cooking them?

Comment: I just wanted to let you know I changed my answer to take back the part about not freezing the pasta. Since it's a sauce filling, the pasta could become soggy. See: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7400/how-do-i-stop-homemade-ravioli-from-going-soggy-storage-issue?rq=1

Comment: @CMB92 Thank you for letting me know about the edit. I haven't tried the recipe yet, but I've accepted your answer because it's very helpful. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipe does say to cook them in the sauce if frozen, but I think it is more a suggestion about another method you could use to cook the ravioli. You could definitely still just boil the frozen ravioli and add them to the sauce. I would probably boil them an additional minute or two being very careful to check to see if they are done past the 4 minute mark. Typically I'd say if the ravioli float, they are done, but the bolognese sauce filling may be too heavy to allow the ravioli to float.

To cook them directly in the sauce, I would heat the sauce up and then add the ravioli so that they make a single layer and can be nestled into the sauce. I would probably cook them 6-7 minutes from the time the sauce comes back to a simmer, but once again, I'd be very careful to watch them. Ravioli is usually pretty easy to tell if it is done and since it will be in the sauce you can easily poke one in the pan, you shouldn't have trouble getting it right.

EDIT: I would actually not recommend refrigerating this recipe rather than freezing it because the sauce filling could make the pasta soggy unlike a cheese filling.